# Clarification Wanted: Conditional Probability Formula

Tags: probability

I asked about the application of the conditional probability formula from my teacher, but I guess he just didn't want to clarify the issue, or he had his own method of putting the answer to paper. (My teacher just uses the favorableCases/sampleSpace method, I think.)

*Problem statement: What is the probability that a component which is still working after*
*800 hours will last for at least 900 hours?*

Using the table to get probabilities:

[image]

### P(A|E) = P(A intersection E)   / (P(E)

- event A: lifespan 900hrs or more
- event E: lifespan 800hrs or more

In my opinion, if we wanted to use the formula, we could calculate the intersection probability like this:

(amountOfComponents in intersection)/(totalComponents)= 1030/1500=0,686666...
This method of calculating intersection probability is the same as if you had a single die-roll, and you wanted to get intersection of two events such as
Event1: roll even, Event2 roll >=4.

P(E) = 1270/ 1500 =0,846666...

Hence the answer will be as follows:
0,686666/0,846666 = about 0,811023

Comment: The number of components with more than 900hrs lifespan is $210+820=1030$. The number of components with more than 800hrs lifespan is $210+820+240=1270$. Thus the answer is ...

Comment: Well, if we wanted to justify the answer, I would imagine that we would have a suitably reduced sample space in this case. And we would use classic probability principle favorableOutcomes/sampleSpace = 1030/1270=0,811023... So that in the end it seems that the answer is same with either method

Answer (score 1):

Teacher's method:
$$P(L\ge 900|L\ge 800)=\frac{\text{favorable}}{\text{total}}=\frac{P(L\ge 900)}{P(L\ge 800)}=\frac{1030}{1270}.$$
Your method:
$$P(L\ge 900|L\ge 800)=\frac{P((L\ge 900)\cap (L\ge 800)}{P(L\ge 800)}=\frac{\frac{P(L\ge 900)}{P(L\ge 0)}}{\frac{P(L\ge 800)}{P(L\ge 0)}}=\frac{P(L\ge 900)}{P(L\ge 800)}=\frac{1030}{1270}.$$
As you see both methods result in the same answer, though the first is simpler.

Comment: thank you for saving my sanity xD! and providing some clarity, I got exam tomorrow and it always helps to understand probability math as deeply as possible... I think that it tends to reduce mistakes when you know what you are doing...